# Advert does not appear for every three clicks

Tags: java, android

I thought I got this working but I haven't. Basically I am counting the number of clicks the user is doing and as a test I want to state for every three clicks (the number of clicks divides by 3), then display an interstitial advert.

The problem I have realised is for the first three clicks or the first number that divides into 3, it shows the advert. However if I continue with the clicks then the advert never appears again.

If I go back a page and then come back to the current page and click 3 times again, then the adevert is displayed.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get the advert to constantly appear based on my number of clicks condition and not for the first three clicks after the page is open?

```
public class Content extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button selectAnotherButton;
    TextView clickCountText;
    int getClickCountInt;

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);

        MobileAds.initialize(Content.this, "ca-app-pub-...");
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(Content.this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-.../...");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        final SharedPreferencesManager prefManager = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(Content.this);
        clickCountText = findViewById(R.id.click_count);
        clickCountText.setText(Integer.toString(prefManager.getClicks()));
        getClickCountInt = Integer.parseInt(clickCountText.getText().toString());

        selectAnotherButton = findViewById(R.id.button_select_another);

        selectAnotherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getClickCountInt++;
                clickCountText.setText(Integer.toString(prefManager.increaseClickCount()));


                if(getClickCountInt % 3 == 0){

                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    } else {
                        Log.d("ADVERT", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
                    }
                }

            }
        });


    }



}
```

Comment: Instead of doing `%` why not just rest `getClickCountInt` when it becomes 0 and also initialize `getClickCountInt = 0`

Comment: I prefer every three clicks because I have other things that are activated when the click count moves further ahead :)